# How can I use `appendChild` to add unlimited File Upload fields?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Im a little new to JavaScript.

I am going to have a file upload field. I want to add an `onclick` to the file upload field to add additional file upload fields.

So I'm thinking something like:

```
i=0
function addfile() { 
document.getElementById("form_name").appendChild(<input type=\"file\" name=\"file1\"" +     "i++" + " />)}
```

...then...

```
<input type="file" onclick="addfile();" />
```

(I know this syntax is probably terrible/missing things, I'm just trying to layout the concept I think I am supposed to be using.)

Can you get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This encapsulates the `i` variable.

```
(function() { 
    var i = 0;
    window.addfile = function() { 
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'file';
        input.name = 'file' + i++;

        document.getElementById('form_name').appendChild(input);
    }
})();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/9aEyN/).

Comment: Ahh that looks much better! So basically just to sum up, add that code to the head, and then add 

    <input type="file" id="form_name"  onclick="addfile();" />

And that'll add a second file field after that one when i fill in the first one? And 3rd one after that and so on? 

Thanks so much, great help!

Comment: @JonahKatz: Yep, refer to the fiddle. You may want to consider using attaching the event in the JavaScript file itself though.

Comment: Oh didnt see that link before! Thats great! Perfect! 

If you dont mind helping with one more quick thing, any way to remove an upload field?

Comment: @JonahKatz: Use `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)`. If you need more help, you should probably ask a new question.